# C#: Generating Runtime Query and Executing

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, dynamicquery

I have been working on a project where the requirements of the customer is to provide the configuration access of parsing the `RSS Feed in XML Format` to user according to his requirement. After selecting the different parameters, a query is generated (`LINQ to XML`) and all the filters like `Value.StartsWith/EndsWith/Contains` are unknown. There can be unlimited filters but not out of the above three `(StartsWith/EndsWith/Contains)`. I have this query in a String variable.

**My Question**
is that, can we execute a query generated at runtime after the users selections ?
The query is more likely to look like this

```
xmldoc.Descendants("item")
      .Where(c =>c.Element("description").Value.StartsWith("some text") 
             && c.Element(description).Value.Contains("some text") 
      .Select(c => c.Element(description).Value).Single();
```

If anyone knows that, is this possible or not. If yes where should i look next.
thanks

Comment: I think you have an incoherence in your && and || operators.

Comment: Oh yeah thats just a example query, main thing is to exectue query at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. My favorite variant is to use [PredciateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to dynamicly build queries.

Comment: Thanks, let me go through it.